# Gridview or Relativelayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I dont know which Layout fits better to my needs.

I want to have 4 Buttons on the left and 4 Buttons on the right.
And if i implement Drag and Drop on these buttons, i want to drag one button over another. 
If the button isnt completly dragged over the other button it should get back to its old position, otherwise it should overlay the button.

I dont know which Layout is better for this... can you give me a tip?

If there is something like a position parameter in the gridview, i would take of course this.. but i havent found any..
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a similar thing with linear layouts. It may suit your need.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layoutLeft"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">

    <ImageButton />
    <ImageButton />
    <ImageButton />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layoutRight"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">

    <ImageButton />
    <ImageButton />
    <ImageButton />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say Relative Layout, since it supports multiple screen sizes and you won't have issues while positioning or re-positioning the buttons.

Comment: yeah.. but how  do you remember the position of the button once it was dragged?

Comment: I guess there's no other way but to keep track of it.